# Where are compiled queries stored on Database?

Tags: database, prepared-statement, pre-compilation

While using prepared statements in java, we say SQL queries are precompiled. I just want to know these queries are precompiled where? At java end or at database end. And if these queries are precompiled at database end then they are stored where , in which object?

Comment: at db end. Why do you need that?

Comment: i dont need that. I just want to know where they are stored on database?

Comment: Why do you need to know where they are stored on database?